# Implementing a typedef that is only defined under a certain condition

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef

While reading the C++11 Standard `20.8.3`, I noticed there were three `typedef`s that are only defined if a certain condition is fulfilled.

How would one typically go about writing such a conditional `typedef`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{

template <class T, bool = std::is_integral<T>::value>
struct maybe_has_a_value_type_or_something_else_impl
{
    using value_type = T;
};

template <class T>
struct maybe_has_a_value_type_or_something_else_impl<T, false>
{
    using something_else = T;
};

} // namespace detail


template <class T>
struct maybe_has_a_value_type_or_something_else
    : public detail::maybe_has_a_value_type_or_something_else_impl<T>
{

};

class Foo
{

};

int main()
{
    maybe_has_a_value_type_or_something_else<int>::value_type          a;
    // maybe_has_a_value_type_or_something_else<int>::something_else   b;
    // maybe_has_a_value_type_or_something_else<Foo>::value_type       c;
    maybe_has_a_value_type_or_something_else<Foo>::something_else      d;
}
```

The similar implementation is used in LLVM `__functional_base` header.

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is through partial specialization. Consider the following implementation of `enable_if` (which is used for a lot of reflection tricks, plus more):

```
template <bool Condition, typename T>
struct enable_if {
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct enable_if<false, T> { /* no typedef */ };
```

The `typedef enable_if<...>::type` only exists when I pass in a statement that evaluates to the constant `true`. For example:

```
typename enable_if<std::is_same<int, int>::value, int>::type; // = int
```

but

```
typename enable_if<std::is_same<int, long double>::value, int>::type; // = error. No typedef inside.
```

This is used often when you want to write generic code for some type `T`, but only if `T` has certain properties, as in C++, "substitution failure is not an error". For example

```
template <typename T, typename = enable_if<is_numeric<T>::value, int>::type>
struct Complex {
    // impl...
};
```

By inserting any type `T` that isn't numeric, I'll get a compiler error. It's dirty, but it works.